# Left Join Lateral is Very Slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, lateral-join

I have the following query

```
WITH time_series AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM generate_series(now() - interval '1days', now(), INTERVAL '1 hour') AS ts
), recent_instances AS (
  SELECT instance_id, 
         (CASE WHEN last_update_granted_ts IS NOT NULL THEN last_update_granted_ts ELSE created_ts END), 
         version, 
         4 status 
  FROM instance_application 
  WHERE group_id=$1 
  AND last_check_for_updates >= now() - interval '1days' 
  ORDER BY last_update_granted_ts DESC
), instance_versions AS (
  SELECT instance_id, created_ts, version, status 
  FROM instance_status_history 
  WHERE instance_id IN (SELECT instance_id 
                        FROM recent_instances) 
    AND status = 4 
  UNION 
  (SELECT * FROM recent_instances) 
  ORDER BY created_ts DESC
)
SELECT ts, 
       (CASE WHEN version IS NULL THEN '' ELSE version END), 
       sum(CASE WHEN version IS NOT null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) total 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM time_series 
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT distinct ON (instance_id) instance_Id, version, created_ts 
      FROM instance_versions 
      WHERE  created_ts <= time_series.ts 
      ORDER BY instance_Id, created_ts DESC
  ) _ ON true
) AS _
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY ts DESC;
```

So instance_versions subquery is executed with every value of timestamps generated from time_series query(see the last select statement). But for some reason the lateral join is very slow,the rows returned by the subquery of lateral join ranges in around 12k-15k(for a single timestamp from time_series query) which is not a big number and the final no of rows returned after the Lateral join ranges from 250k-350k. Is there a way i can optimize this?

Comment: Get rid of the large CTEs, replace them by subqueries. Or: force the CTEs to NOT MATERIALIZED (on Postgre-12)

Comment: Is the `sum()` supposed to be a running total? If yes, then I think you can ditch the lateral join completely and simply use `count(version) over (partition by instance_id order by ts)` and maybe move the `distinct on()` into the CTE directly. The `order by` in the `instance_versions` CTE is also useless and won't be optimized away.

Comment: Unrelated, but `(CASE WHEN last_update_granted_ts IS NOT NULL THEN last_update_granted_ts ELSE created_ts END)` can be simplified to `coalesce(last_update_granted_ts, created_ts)` (it won't matter for performance though, just readability - at least in my eyes)

Comment: `SELECT distinct ON (instance_id)`: your CTEs + UNION machinery is generating  shiploads of tuples, but you need them to be distinct ? (ORDER BY in the subqueries is suspect, too)

Comment: Can you please post your execution plan?  The `ORDER BY` in `recent_instances` and `instance_versions` is likely forcing unnecessary sorting steps in your plan.

Comment: Sure so from the distinct list of instances that I got from instance_versions I want to iterate over the timestamps in time_series CTE and for each timestamp I want to run the subquery mentioned in the lateral join, then on the rows returned from lateral JOIN I count versions with the same timestamp and version.

Comment: @wildplasser i tried removing ORDER BY but it didn't had any effect on query time, and yes i agree that CTES + union is generating too much tuples going upto 13k sometime.
Also you mentioned that replacing CTEs with subqueries would help but does CTEs cause impact in querying(sorry for asking this lame question but I am a little new to the SQL world)

Comment: Your `_ ON true` is essentially a cross join / carthesian product. If you look at the query plan (use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`) , you will probably see a slow nested loop on two bulky CTE scans, followed by some sorting aggregating, dedupping. IOW: rethink your query.